# How to get a count of days between two dates in Openerp

Tags: python, odoo

I need to calculate number of days between any given two days in hr_holidays class and need to ignore the days from bellow given hr_company_holidays class from that calculation.
like in **hr_holiday** class this method calling for get the calculation done....

```
def _get_number_of_days(self, date_from, date_to):
   diffdays = end_date-startdate+hr_comapny_holidays.dates

return diffdays
```

how to do that ? I need to know the other lines for above function

"**hr_company_holidays**"

```
    class hr_company_holidays(osv.osv):
  _name = "hr.company.holidays"
  _description = "hr.company.holidays"
  _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Holiday', size=256, required=True),
        'date': fields.date('Day', size=256, required=True),
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to get the number of "work days" between two dates. Do you want to count weekends?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do, try to clarify your question.

Comment: I am sorry if it is unclear, yes what I need want to do is calculate days between two days ignoring holidays in between those two days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the `datetime` module. Convert date to date objects and then subtract them.

```
from datetime import datetime
from openerp import tools

start_date = datetime.strptime("1995-03-13", tools.DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT)
end_date = datetime.strptime("1995-03-19", tools.DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT)

delta = d1 - d0
print(delta.days)
```

A date field in OpenERP/Odoo is in string format, `YYYY-MM-DD`. Your method can take in either date objects or string (which you should convert to date objects using the `strptime()` method) and inside your method, just do something similar above. Lastly, since you have some dates to ignore, simply test if `hr_holiday_start_date < hr_company_holiday_date < hr_holiday_end_date`, count the dates that pass this and subtract it to the difference.

**Update:**

Your method should look something like this in new API:

```
 @api.one
 def _get_number_of_days(self, start_date, end_date):
     # start_date and end_date are date strings in YYYY-MM-DD format
     # First, get the hr_company_holidays models
     hr_company_holidays_model = self.env['hr_company_holidays']
     # Then, get how many holidays that are within start_date and end_date
     holiday_count = hr_company_holidays.search_count([('date', '>', start_date), ('date', '<', end_date)])
     # Convert start_date and end_date to date objects
     start_date_obj = datetime.strptime(start_date, tools.DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT)
     end_date_obj = datetime.strptime(end_date, tools.DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT)
     # Get the delta object
     delta = end_date_obj - start_date_obj
     # Lastly, get number of days, ignoring holidays
     total_days = delta.days - holiday_count
     # It's up to you what to do next with this total_days
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the reply macdelacruz... I already set  a validation rule to check whether the start_date < end_date and I have no idea how to get a hr_company_holiday_date in to a "for" loop which will going to compare the dates. Please be kind enough to help me with that.

Comment: @ManishaS I updated my answer. You don't need loop at all since you can search the database directly for records whose date field is within `start_date` and `end_date`.

Comment: When I using this it says
TypeError: search_count() takes at least 4 arguments (2 given)

Comment: Are you using the new API? Which version of Odoo are you using? The old API requires thay you provide that you also provide the uid, the cursor and the context as well.

Comment: yep , it worked .. thank you so much macdelacruz... I have modified some of my other functions according to that ... thank you so much again n' again